# What is the 'section' field in a google classroom course used for?

Tags: google-classroom

I've noticed there is a `section` field for a `course` in the Google Classroom API. It doesn't appear in the user interface (that I can find anywhere). What is it supposed to be used for? Does it alter the UI in any way? Can I put by own (non-user-accessible) data in there?

Answer (score 0):

It does appear in the UI, as a sort of sub-heading under the name:

[image: Screenshot showing "MySection" section]

(Change it by hitting the "three dots" in the screenshot, and selecting "Rename".)

Answer (score 0):

Setting is a field that you can use for class details.  To get to the front end where users input the section information on an open-ended filed, go into course setting to access class details.

[image: Snapshot of Class Detail screen where users input section information]